# Save results in a .txt file using makefile, but in a relative path

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, txt

I have a cpp code that prints some data, I want it to save the results in a txt file, but I want it to be in a different directory.

My data tree

```
|
|--Code
|   |--Oscilador.cpp
|   |--makefile
|
|--Resultados
|   |--(Where I want the txt to be save in)
```

My make file code is this

```
Oscilador.x:Oscilador.cpp
    g++-10 -o0 Oscilador.cpp -o Oscilador.x

Resultados.txt:Oscilador.x
    ./Oscilador.x > ./Resultados/
    rm Oscilador.x
```

When I runed the make file it says:

```
:Codigo Felipe$ make Resultados.txt
./Oscilador.x > Resultados/Resultados.txt
/bin/sh: Resultados/Resultados.txt: No such file or directory
make: *** [Resultados.txt] Error 1
```

I wonder how can I fix it.

Comment: the relative path is `../Resultados/Resultadoes.txt` not `Resultados/Resultadoes.txt`

Comment: @Acuervoc does the solution I provided works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the below code which will fix this issue.

```
Oscilador.x:Oscilador.cpp
    g++ Oscilador.cpp -o Oscilador.x

Resultados.txt:Oscilador.x
    # Output to Resultados.txt file under Resultados directory which is present one folder behind
    ./Oscilador.x > ../Resultados/Resultados.txt
    rm Oscilador.x
```

The above code runs succesfully if the directory Resultados is already created.
If the directory doesnot exists and you want to create it before generation of Resultdos.txt then use the below code

```
Oscilador.x:Oscilador.cpp
    g++ Oscilador.cpp -o Oscilador.x

Resultados.txt:Oscilador.x
    # create directory Resultados one folder behind  if it does not exist
    mkdir -p ../Resultados
    ./Oscilador.x > ../Resultados/Resultados.txt
    rm Oscilador.x
```